# How do we call an R object if it's named with a number?

Tags: r

Maybe it's a silly question but I have a problem:

I absolutely need to call some of my data frames on R by numbers. So I have several data frames that are called 1, 2 ,3 ...

How can I call them? 
If I just apply a function like summary, `summary(1)`  will just tell me the summary of the number 1, not of my dataframe.

`\` ou `/` don't work. I also tried `" "` but it doesn't work either. I don't know what kind of special character I have to use. 
I tried searching on the web or on the R documentation but I didn't found anything.

So, does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: ``summary(`1`)``   Use backticks

Comment: Use the backtick. However, a name should be a name and not a number. Plus, you should have a named list rather than several objects polluting your environment.

Comment: Oh, thank you, you saved me! I'll follow your advice :)

Comment: can someone post some combination of these comments as an answer please ... ?

Comment: Just adding some more information to you: you'll have to use backticks also if the names are started by a number (e.g.: `1D`) or if the names have some special character (e.g.: `X-Y`). Pay attention if you are creating new variables with special characters because they can be automatically changed by R.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you :)

Comment: "I absolutely need to call some of my data frames on R by numbers. So I have several data frames that are called 1, 2 ,3 ..." That's bad design. These data.frames should be in a list, then you could simply do `mylist[["1"]]` or `mylist[[1]]` and it would be much easier to iterate over them with a loop..

Comment: Well, originally, it's a huge matrix issued of single cell sequencing that I couldn't import in R directly so I separated it into multiple parts ... So, I don't know if it's a good idea to insert them all into a list, the list object will be huge, I think R will crash if I do it.

Comment: If they are loaded into R sequentially, why do they need different names? The results you compute from them need different names but should probably also be in one object (possibly a list). I have yet to encounter a valid reason to use numbers as symbols for objects in R.

Comment: I loop through the different files inside a directory ```path = "path" |  out.file<-"" |
file.names <- dir(path) |  for(i in 1:length(file.names)){ ``` and then I create multiple seurat objects from the Seurat package that allows me to study those single cell count matrices by doing this ```assign(toString(i), CreateSeuratObject( ... ) ``` , allowing me to filter the matrices one by one, erase the raw ones and at the end, combining them together to create a big Seurat object that will anyway be smaller once the filtering will be done on each dataframe.

Comment: So I'm using just numbers as a transitional name by using the numbers i from the loop. Indeed I could change the names and use something else than the numbers of the loop but I thought it is more convenient like this.

Comment: Why can't you do something like `mylist <- list(); for (i in ...) {temp <- CreateSeuratObject( ... ); mylist[[i]] <- processingfunction(temp)}; rm(temp)`?

Comment: Indeed, I could. If it's so not recommended to call my R objects by numbers, I'll change my code following your advice. Thank you :)

Comment: The big advantage is that with lists you can do stuff like `lapply(mylist, somefunction)` and possibly even `do.call(rbind, mylist)`.